# WCF - posting JSON to an endpoint - what should the request content body look like?

Tags: wcf, json, fiddler

I've just spent a couple of hours debugging and looking through questions like [POSTing JSON to WCF REST Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398809/posting-json-to-wcf-rest-endpoint) and [Generic WCF JSON Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297903/generic-wcf-json-deserialization), but currently I think my code and/or debugging is failing at quite a basic level...

I've set up a WCF service like:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class AutomationService : IAutomationService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "getNextCommand")]
    public CommandBase GetNextCommand(int timeoutInMilliseconds)
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

where IAutomationService is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAutomationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypeProvider))]
    CommandBase GetNextCommand(int timeoutInMilliseconds);
}
```

and I've now got this service successfully setup with SOAP and JSON endpoints.

However... I can't seem to work out how to call the service using variables passed in the ContentBody from Fiddler.

For example, I can call the service with a POST on the Uri - e.g.

```
   POST  http://localhost:8085/phoneAutomation/jsonAutomate/getNextCommand?timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
```

However, if I try to put the content in the body, then I get an exception. e.g.

```
POST http://localhost:8085/phoneAutomation/jsonAutomate/getNextCommand
Host: localhost:8085
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
Accept: application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: Orchrd-=%7B%22Exp-N42-Settings%22%3A%22open%22%2C%22Exp-N42-New%22%3A%22open%22%7D
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json

{"timeoutInMilliseconds":10000}
```

fails with:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   System.Int32. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'. See
>   server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) at
>
> ...

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong (other than using WCF!) - I'm just not sure what shape the JSON {"timeoutInMilliseconds":10000} is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the "body style" of a WCF REST service is "Bare", meaning that for operations with a single input, the value of the operation should go "as is" without any object wrapping it. That means in your case that this will work:

```
POST http://localhost:8085/phoneAutomation/jsonAutomate/getNextCommand
Host: localhost:8085
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
...
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/json

10000
```

One more thing, not directly related to your question: if you define a service contract in the interface, you should also add any "contract-related" attributes (such as `WebInvoke`) in the interface as well. That would make your code look like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class AutomationService : IAutomationService
{
    public CommandBase GetNextCommand(int timeoutInMilliseconds)
    {
        // stuff
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IAutomationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypeProvider))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "getNextCommand")]
    CommandBase GetNextCommand(int timeoutInMilliseconds);
}
```

And another info: if you wanted to send the request the same way as you had originally (`{"tiemoutInMilliseconds":10000}`), you can set the `BodyStyle` property in the `[WebInvoke]` attribute to Wrapped (or WrappedRequest):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAutomationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypeProvider))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               UriTemplate = "getNextCommand",
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    CommandBase GetNextCommand(int timeoutInMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: I think I love you. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Been and tested it now... everything you say works... now I know I love you. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. Will also go off and tidy up my contract too.